# Play Framework setting javaSource and javaHome

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am currently running a play app in dev mode on my linux server. Java is already installed on the server, but I want to user a different version. Currently, play is using the wrong version. I see that there are two settings javaHome and javaSource listed, but I'm not sure how to set them

How can I tell play what location to use for its java source, I'm using play 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
javaSource := new File( "pathToSource")
javaHome := Option( new File("pathToJavaHome") )
```